# InvalidCastException implementing .net events in native c++ with managed wrapper

Tags: c#, events, visual-c++, delegates, callback

I am attempting to invoke managed events from native c++, by using a managed wrapper for a native  class, and then using the managed wrapper via dll from C#.  However, I receive a InvalidCastException runtime error that I don't know how to resolve, or even what it means.  My implementation is as follows:

The header for ManagedClass is

```
#pragma once
#include "NativeClass.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace NativeLibrary
{
     public delegate void ReportProgressDelegate(Double ^completionPercentage);

     public ref class ManagedClass
     {
         public:
         ManagedClass();

         event ReportProgressDelegate ^OnReportProgress;
         void RaiseReportProgress(Double ^completionPercentage);

         void CallTestFunction();

         private:
         NativeClass *_NativeClass;
         ReportProgressDelegate ^ReportProgress;
     };
}
```

while ManagedClass source file is

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ManagedClass.h"
#include "TestFunction.h"

using namespace NativeLibrary;

ManagedClass::ManagedClass()
{
     _NativeClass = new NativeClass();
     ReportProgress = gcnew ReportProgressDelegate(this, &ManagedClass::RaiseReportProgress);
     _NativeClass->ProgressFunction = (void (*)(double))Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(ReportProgress).ToPointer();

      void ManagedClass::RaiseReportProgress(System::Double ^completionPercentage)
      {
           OnReportProgress(completionPercentage);
      }

      void ManagedClass::CallTestFunction()
      {
           TestFunction(*_NativeClass);
      }
}
```

Here NativeClass is defined in its own header file

```
#pragma once

class NativeClass
{
     public:
     NativeClass() {};
     void (*ProgressFunction)(double);
};
```

as is TestFunction

```
#pragma once
#include "NativeClass.h"

void TestFunction(NativeClass& nativeClass)
{
     nativeClass.ProgressFunction(50.0);
     return;
}
```

I set up a C# program to test the event.  My C# program consists of

```
NativeLibrary.ManagedClass managedClass = new NativeLibrary.ManagedClass();
managedClass.OnReportProgress += new NativeLibrary.ReportProgressDelegate(managedClass_OnReportProgress);
managedClass.CallTestFunction();
```

where the managedClass_OnReportProgress event is defined as

```
void managedClass_OnReportProgress(ValueType completionPercentage)
{
     MessageBox.Show("report progress event triggered");
}
```

The problem occurs when I call the function CallTestFunction.  When I step through using the debugger, it successfully makes it inside the native TestFunction.  However, when it reaches the closing brace of TestFunction, I get the runtime error:
"InvalidCastException was unhandled.  No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))"

I'm really clueless as to how to resolve this problem, or what the source of it is.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public delegate void ReportProgressDelegate(Double ^completionPercentage);
```

Double is a value type.  You should only use the ^ for reference types.  I'm guessing it bombs when it tries to convert a boxed Double (an Object) to a native double.  Delete the ^

Comment: This is the most spectacular failure mode of this common bug I have seen so far.